# How to scale a ratio to a limited range?

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling

I'm writing [an app](https://github.com/dogweather/repo-health-check) and I want to present some ratios normalized on a scale of 0 to 10. It's information like (number of issues resolved : number of issues remaining open).

My idea is to write a function, and a few of its inputs & outputs would be:

```
f(0)   ->  0
f(0.1) ->  1.0
f(1)   ->  5.0
f(10)  ->  9.0
f(inf) -> 10.0
```

So, the input is a real number >= 0, and the output is a real between 0 and 10 inclusive.

So my immediate question is: Is there a well known formula that would create this kind of output? I got pretty close with some variations of y = a/(1 + be^(-kx)), but I'm mostly randomly guessing.

I'm interested in any way to solve this, as well as how to generate solutions for it.

Also: since I'm programming this, I could do this with a few functions which I alternatively invoke, depending on the input.

EDIT: Here's @A.S.'s solution, y=10*(x/(1+x)) which looks pretty much perfect:

[image]

This is [my javascript implementation](https://github.com/dogweather/repo-health-check/blob/master/metrics.js#L30-L35).

Comment: Can you have more than eleven inputs?

Comment: Yes @GitGud the input is a real >= 0, and the output is a real bet. 0 and 10 inclusive.

Comment: $f(x)=arctan(x)\frac {20}{\pi}$ isn't bad.  Do you need it to hit all those early points exactly?

Comment: @Dogweather OK, I made the mistake of assuming that the outputs had to be integers, hence my seemingly odd question.

Comment: $f(x)\approx 10\frac x {1+x}$

Comment: Thanks @lulu I'll see what that looks like. It's pretty important to hit those points because they're very meaningful. I.e., if the ratio of issues received to issues resolved is 1:1, then that'd be a 5 out of 10. As the ratio gets higher, it limits at 10. As it gets lower below 1, it limits at zero.

Comment: In fact, I'd argue it's THE function you should use since $x\to \frac{x}{1+x}$ is transformation from odds (your input) to probabilities - very meaningful output.

Comment: @A.S. that's amazing: http://imgur.com/SgcubT7 How did you do that?

Comment: I switch my vote to $10\frac {x}{1+x}$ as per the recommendation of @A.S.

Comment: Deleted my question about the nearest integer function. I'm the second person to believe the outputs need be integers for some reason.

Comment: @Brody my fault: i phrased the Q at first in terms of integers, and then realized that's unnecessary.